# Why did my Linqpad just deactivate itself?

Tags: linqpad

I'm using Linqpad v4.45.05 on Windows Server 2012 virtual machine. I'm on a isolated network so I had to perform an "offline activation" (which was a complete nightmare). Today, I rebooted my VM and now my Linqpad is no longer activate. Do I have any way to recover my activation? Why did this happen and how do I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Linqpad support.

Comment: @EricAndres I asked here because the creator of Linqpad commonly uses Stack Overflow. Linqpad is a programming tool and other users of Stack Overflow may encounter this so I think it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some general things to check:

- LINQPad activations on virtual machines are tied both to the machine and the underlying hardware, so if the latter changes, the activation may become invalid.
- When activating, choose the option to activate all users (rather than the current user) unless you plan to always use the same login.
- Activations on Azure VMs are not fully supported on versions prior to v4.47.05, which is still [in beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) at time of writing.

Comment: I appreciate the response (as well as the email you sent me).